# how to display all the days between 2 dates in PHP

Tags: php

I want to display all the day of date between 2 dates

```
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $i++ . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['instructorname'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['batchname'] . "</td>";
echo '<td>'; for($i=$startdate;$i<=$todate;$i++){ echo $i.'</br>' ;} echo '</td>';

echo "<td><a href='sendmessage.php?batchname=".$row['batchname']." & $i'><button type='button'name='enable'class='btn btn-primary'>Send Message</button></a> </td>";                            
echo "</tr>";
```

how to display day of each value of $i

Comment: What is `startdate`, `$todate`?

Comment: $startdate=$row['fromdate'];
 $todate=$row['todate'];

Comment: You expect me to guess what values are there?

Comment: $startdate and $todate are  date  values from database

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the days between to dates to define a function.
Apply this code:

```
<?php echo '<td>'; echo dateDifference($startdate ,$startdate ).'</td>'; ?>
```

Now try with **dateDifference** function code.

```
<?php
function dateDifference($startdate , $startdate , $differenceFormat = '%a' )
{
    $datetime1 = date_create($date_1);
    $datetime2 = date_create($date_2);

    $interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);

    return $interval->format($differenceFormat);

}
?>
```